# Use small caps in bibliography for institutional authors

Tags: biblatex, small-caps

I'm using biblatex-apa to define the layout of my bibliography. Now I'm citing several (internal) documents from institutions or news websites, which now appear in the document using their abbreviation. I would like to make these abbreviations appear in small caps. Actually, I want all abbreviated institutions to appear in small caps. Is this possible? I now split my bibliography using tags (exported from Zotero), so I assume a tag might also enable the citation to appear as small caps in the text? Anyone knows how to do this?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, date=year, natbib=true, sorting=nyt, sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\bibliography{Zotero}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Literature review}
This is some text with a double reference \cite{nos_weeralarm_2009, ns_volle_2013}.


\printbibliography[notkeyword=internal]
\printbibliography[title={Internal Documents}, keyword=internal]
\end{document}
```

And the content of my Zotero.bib:

```
@online{nos_weeralarm_2009,
title = {Weeralarm en verkeeralarm ingetrokken},
url = {http://nos.nl/l/124074},
titleaddon = {{NOS.nl}},
author = {{NOS}}, %THIS AUTHOR MUST BE PRINTED IN SC
urldate = {2014-02-12},
date = {2009-12-20},
keywords = {gladheid, ijs, ongeluk, openbaar vervoer, schiphol, sneeuw}
}
@report{ns_volle_2013,
location = {Utrecht},
title = {Internal document title}},
institution = {NS},
type = {Internal Document},
author = {{NS}}, % THIS AUTHOR MUST BE PRINTED IN SC
date = {2013},
keywords = {internal}
}
```

Comment: What part is the 'abbreviated institition'?  It is easy to make the field institution appear in small caps, even on a per-type basis; e.g., `\DeclareListFormat[report]{institution}{\textsc{#1}}`, would make institution fields for entry type `@report` appear in small caps.  If some reports need to not have the institution field appear in small caps, then it becomes a little more elaborate.

Comment: For both entries it concerns the author field, since the author is the reference that appears in the text [example: (NOS, 2009) and (NS, 2013)]. Is there some kind of IF condition you can add to your suggestion? Then it might work!

Comment: You mean [in pseudocode]: if keywords=internal, then \textsc{author}; else print author normally ..?

Comment: Don't you want `\textsc{\lowercase {#1}}`?

Comment: jon, that is exactly what I mean.
cfr, true, since the author is mostly in caps, without '\lowercase'  the smallcaps won't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your citations that require a small caps institution do indeed have the same tag, then it should be possible.

In your MWE however, the two entries do not share a `keyword`, so I added the keyword `instauth` to check for.

What we do is very simple: At every citation command, and before every bibliography entry we check, if the entry has the keyword `instauth`, if so the last name format is set to produce acronyms via `biblatex`'s `\mkbibacro` macro (note that for this to work "[t]he acronym should be given in uppercase letters.", p. 89, the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifkeyword{instauth}
    {\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibacro{#1}}}
    {}%
}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifkeyword{instauth}
    {\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibacro{#1}}}
    {}%
}
```

An alternative redefinition is the shorter

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{%
  \ifkeyword{instauth}
    {\mkbibacro{#1}}
    {#1}}
```

Where the conditional is *inside* the formatting directive. Then there is no need to hook the change into groups where `\ifkeyword` is defined, as was necessary above.

We can even make the detection of `instauth` automatic up to some point. With

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{^\{.+?\}$}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, append, fieldvalue={,instauth}]
    }
  }
}
```

all `author` fields that contain a string wrapped in double curly braces are classed as `instauth`.
This might brake down in some corner cases - as do so many automatic solutions.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, date=year, natbib=true, sorting=nyt, sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{nos_weeralarm_2009,
title = {Weeralarm en verkeeralarm ingetrokken},
url = {http://nos.nl/l/124074},
titleaddon = {{NOS.nl}},
author = {{NOS}}, %THIS AUTHOR MUST BE PRINTED IN SC
urldate = {2014-02-12},
date = {2009-12-20},
keywords = {gladheid, ijs, ongeluk, openbaar vervoer, schiphol, sneeuw}
}
@report{ns_volle_2013,
location = {Utrecht},
title = {Internal document title},
institution = {NS},
type = {Internal Document},
author = {{NS}}, % THIS AUTHOR MUST BE PRINTED IN SC
date = {2013},
keywords = {internal},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{^\{.+?\}$}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, append, fieldvalue={,instauth}]
    }
  }
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{%
  \ifkeyword{instauth}
    {\mkbibacro{#1}}
    {#1}}


\begin{document}
This is some text with a double reference \cite{nos_weeralarm_2009, ns_volle_2013, wilde, cicero}.


\printbibliography[notkeyword=internal]
\printbibliography[title={Internal Documents}, keyword=internal]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I meant. Thnx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Note: As of March 2016 (biblatex 3.3), you need to change \mkbibnamefamily instead of \mkbibnamelast. See also [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/biblatex-3-3-name-formatting).

Comment: Mhhh, I don't know if it is a good idea to edit/answer all questions/answers on this site that mention `\mkbibnamelast`. But this creates a lot of noise. If people run into trouble we can point them to a canonical question. (Note also that the upcoming version of `biblatex` will have a backwards compatibility mode for `\mkbibname...` macros.)

Comment: fair enough. I just wasted an hour trying to figure out what's wrong with my old document and thought I'd help people avoid that. We'll see how often people will ask the question these days....

Comment: Yes, the situation is a bit unfortunate. But a [short search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=\mkbibnamelast) revealed that there are 158 mentions of `\mkbinamelast` alone. I don't think it is a good idea to edit all of them. As I said, if people come here to ask why things don't work we already have a question to point them to.