# BibLaTeX: prevent caps for some authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm using this command:

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

to print all author names in caps. (if they are quoted in text as well as in the biblography). I'm using biblatex with the authoryear-icomp style.

Now I want to apply some kind of filter, to prevent instituions which are enclosed in double curly braces like so

```
author = {{Regionalverband Ruhr}}
```

from being printed in caps (again both in text as well as in the biblography). How could this be achieved?

So

> SELLE, K. (2005): Planen, Steuern, Entwickeln: über den Beitrag öffentlicher Akteure zur Entwicklung von Stadt und Land. Dortmund (=Edition Stadt-Entwicklung).

but

> Ruhr Tourismus GmbH (2017): Marketingstrategie 2017-2022 der Ruhr Tourismus GmbH. Oberhausen.

Comment: Related (but actually the opposite problem): [Use small caps in bibliography for institutional authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166305/35864)

Comment: BTW: Even if your question is reasonably clear without an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) it is still beneficial to provide one. If we have an MWE we can make sure that the suggested answer really works with your set-up. If you use heavily customised styles there is a chance that some of the standard approaches need tweaking before they can be applied.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you use [the fancy annotation feature for fields](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/35864). If you have a corporate author simply add `author+an = {=corporate}`.
With

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \iffieldannotation{corporate}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{#1}}}
```

we then check if we have a `corporate` author or not. Small caps are used only if the author is not corporate.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ruhr,
  author    = {{Regionalverband Ruhr}},
  author+an = {=corporate},
  title     = {Marketingstrategie 2017-2022 der Ruhr Tourismus GmbH},
  year      = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \iffieldannotation{corporate}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,ruhr},

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

The advantages of the annotation really come into play once we realise that we can add annotation to specific names.
With `author+an = {1=corporate},` only the first name is `corporate`. We then need to use

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{corporate}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{#1}}}
```

Note `\ifitemannotation` instead of `\iffieldannotation`.

In

```
@misc{ruhr,
  author    = {{Regionalverband Ruhr} and Anne Elk},
  author+an = {1=corporate},
  title     = {Marketingstrategie 2017-2022 der Ruhr Tourismus GmbH},
  year      = {2017},
}
```

then, "Anne Elk" gets small caps, but "Regionalverband Ruhr" doesn't.

You will of course have to count the number of authors and give the correct number even if there is only one author

```
  author    = {{Regionalverband Ruhr}},
  author+an = {1=corporate},
```

and

```
  author    = {Anne Elk and {Regionalverband Ruhr}},
  author+an = {2=corporate},
```

This will naturally also work for the `editor` field and any other name field.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Never heard of this annonation feature for fields. I will definitely check it out.
Now I only have to find a way to add this field to my bib file using [zotero-better-bibtex](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex).

Comment: Well, this is powerful! Do you not even need an additional package for that? There is none in your code, so I guess not, just wanted to make sure it wasn't forgotten.

Comment: @schmattes The feature is fairly new (OK, it's been a year now) and unique to `biblatex` (with Biber), so I'm not sure if Zotero or `zotero-better-bibtex` supports it at the moment. But maybe you can ask the authors of better-bibtex to include support if you can't add the annotation manually.

Comment: @thymaro No additional package is needed, this comes directly from `biblatex` - which is really powerful. But it needs the Biber backend, it won't work if you use BibTeX (which is officially considered a legacy backend and only kept for backwards compatibility).

Comment: For those wondering how to add this field with `zotero-better-bibtex` adding `biblatex{"author+an":"=corporate"}`or `biblatex{"author+an":"1=corporate"}`to the extra field does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

You also can filter with a `keyword`, say `nosc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ruhr,
  author = {{Regionalverband Ruhr}},
  title = {Marketingstrategie 2017-2022 der Ruhr Tourismus GmbH},
  year = {2017},
  keywords = {nosc}
}
@book{selle05,
author = {Selle, K},
title = {Planen, Steuern, Entwickeln: über den Beitrag öffentlicher Akteure zur Entwicklung von Stadt und Land},
year = {2005},
publisher = {Edition Stadt-Entwicklung},
location = {Dortmund}
}
    \end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifkeyword{nosc}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Siehe \cite{ruhr, selle05}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]