# Special names in footnotes and bibliography

Tags: biblatex

In my footnotes and bibliography I occasionally have special author names that should not be printed with the usual pattern (Last name, First name).

For example: `Athanasius Alexandrinus` needs to stay that way because "Alexandrinus" is not his last name but the name of the city in which he was the bishop.

I solved this problem by writing his name as `{Athanasius Alexandrinus}` in the bibliography. But, now publisher wants me to add small caps to the last names. When I do that this type of special names are also produced in small caps, although they are not last names.

So here is what I get:

[image]

**Athanasius Alexandrinus in the first footnote needs to stay together but not in small caps.**

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1857,
        Address = {Parisiis},
        Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
        Booktitle = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
        Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
        Pages = {37-40},
        Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
        Shortauthor = {Ath.},
        Shorttitle = {ep. Marcell.},
        Title = {Epistula ad Marcellinum de interpretatione psalmorum},
        Volume = {27},
        Year = {1857}}
@article{stead1997,
    Author = {Christopher Stead},
    Journal = {Studia Patristica},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Pages = {39-52},
    Title = {Was Arius a Neoplatonist?},
    Volume = {32},
    Year = {1997}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\normalfont{#1}}% NO ITALIC IN FIRST NAMES
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}% SMALL CAPS IN LAST NAMES
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}% SMALL CAPS IN LAST NAMES
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}% SMALL CAPS IN LAST NAMES
\DeclareNameAlias{upshape}{given-family}% SMALL CAPS IN LAST NAMES
\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.46\itemsep}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\makeatletter%
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit}%
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}%
     {\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}}%
\makeatother%
%
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1857}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{stead1997}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1857}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a way to tell `biblatex` not to output a name in small caps in these cases. The "best" solution is to use data annotations, see §3.6 *Data Annotations* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and [PLK's answer to *Make specific author bold using biblatex*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/35864), [Overloading Author+an / highlighting more than one author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349570/35864).

A very, very similar question is [BibLaTeX: prevent caps for some authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378469/35864).

Simply tell `biblatex` not to use small caps with the annotation `nosc`. You will need to set the annotation for both `author` and `shortauthor`

```
@incollection{athanasius1857,
  author         = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
  author+an      = {1=nosc}, 
  shortauthor    = {Ath.},
  shortauthor+an = {1=nosc},
  title          = {Epistula ad Marcellinum de interpretatione psalmorum},
  shorttitle     = {ep. Marcell.},
  editor         = {Jacques Paul Migne},
  booktitle      = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
  pages          = {37-40},
  volume         = {27},
  date           = {1857},
  address        = {Parisiis},
  publisher      = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
}
```

then you can use

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\ifitemannotation{nosc}{#1}{\textsc{#1}}}
```

**This feature needs Biber, BibTeX is not enough.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1857,
  author         = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
  author+an      = {1=nosc}, 
  shortauthor    = {Ath.},
  shortauthor+an = {1=nosc},
  title          = {Epistula ad Marcellinum de interpretatione psalmorum},
  shorttitle     = {ep. Marcell.},
  editor         = {Jacques Paul Migne},
  booktitle      = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
  pages          = {37-40},
  volume         = {27},
  date           = {1857},
  address        = {Parisiis},
  publisher      = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
}
@article{stead1997,
  author   = {Christopher Stead},
  title    = {Was Arius a Neoplatonist?},
  journal  = {Studia Patristica},
  volume   = {32},
  year     = {1997},
  pages    = {39-52},
  keywords = {secondary},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=biber, idemtracker=true]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\ifitemannotation{nosc}{#1}{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{upshape}{given-family}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}%
}

\setlength\bibitemsep{0.46\itemsep}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[See][56]{athanasius1857}
\blindtext\footcite[See][22]{stead1997}
\blindtext\footcite[See][56]{athanasius1857}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\renewenvironment{thebibliography}%` did nothing, and the `\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}` was too eager for me, so I removed them. I also added `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}` so that the "S." does not need to be given in the postnote.